# cypress record video did not work in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, cypress

since migrating our test from bitbucket to gitlab the video is no longer recorded during runs in the pipeline. has anyone encountered a similar problem? cypress version 7.3.0

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  npm_config_cache: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.npm"
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/Cypress"


cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - .cache/*
    - cache/Cypress
    - node_modules
    - build

  image: cypress/browsers:node14.15.0-chrome86-ff82
  stage: build
  script:
    - yarn install
    - npx cypress cache path
    - npx cypress cache list

phone-sanity-tests-development:
  image: cypress/browsers:node14.15.0-chrome86-ff82
  stage: test
  parallel: 15
  script:
    - yarn cypress:run-phone-development-sanity
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cypress/screenshots/**
      - cypress/videos/**
      - cypress/reports/**
      - cypress/projects/phone/puppeteer/videos/**
```

Comment: Do you need to create the folders to hold the artefacts?

Answer (score 1):

Here: `- yarn cypress:run-phone-development-sanity` you need to add `--record`.

In order to tell cypress to record and make screenshots you need to configure this on the run command in yml file.

This link is nice example how Cypress team configures their gitlab-ci.yml:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: You also miss, "when: on_failure" and "expire_in: {1 day} "